# not adding duplicates to playlist

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, playlist

I have a ul with a bunch of songs that can be added to another ul to form a playlist.
however i do not want the same song added twice I'm doing this through jquery but cannot get the result i want here is the http://jsfiddle.net/mcaJS/ and here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Playlist Mania</h1>

<form>
    <input type="text" id="containsContent">
    <input type="button" value="Filter" id="filterButton">
    <input type="button" value="Add to Playlist" id="addButton">
    <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clearButton">

<h2>Selected Songs</h2>

    <ul id="playlist"></ul>

<h2>Albums to choose from</h2>

    <div class="album">
         <h3>The Dark Side of the Moon</h3>

         <h4>Pink Floyd</h4>

        <ol>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speak_to_Me" data- length="1:30">Speak to Me</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathe_(Pink_Floyd_song)" data- length="2:43">Breathe</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a data-length="3:36">On the Run</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a data-length="7:01">Time</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Gig_in_the_Sky" data-length="4:36">The Great Gig in the Sky</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a data-length="6:22">Money</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a data-length="7:46">Us and Them</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a data-length="3:25">Any Colour You Like</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_Damage_(song)" data-length="3:48">Brain Damage</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"><a data-length="2:03">Eclipse</a>
            </li>
            <ol>
    </div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("input#filterButton").click(filterContentAndCheck);
    $("input#clearButton").click(clearAll);
    $("input#addButton").click(addToPlaylist);
});
var clearAll = function () {
    $("*").removeClass("highlight");
    $("form").get(0).reset();
    $("form input:checked").attr("checked", false);
};
var filterContentAndCheck = function () {
    var lookFor = $("input#containsContent").val();
    clearAll();
    $("li a:contains('" + lookFor + "')").parent().addClass("highlight");
    $("li.highlight input:checkbox").attr("checked", true);
};

var addToPlaylist = function () {
    $("form input:checked").parent().each(function () {
        var song = $(this).text();
        var contains = $("ul#playlist li:contains()");
        console.log(contains);
        if (contains > 0) {
            alert("do not add");
        } else {
            $("ul#playlist").append("<li>" + song + "</li>");
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var contains = $("ul#playlist li:contains()");
```

supposed to be

```
var contains = $("ul#playlist li:contains(" + song  + ")");
```

Otherwise you can have a array and push the songs when added to the playlist. And check the array first before adding it to the playlist.

And your condition should check for the Length of `contains`

```
 if (contains> 0) {
```

supposed to be

```
 if (contains.length > 0) {
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/SsVnS/)**

Comment: Thanks alot i was adding the .length() to the contains variable not the if statement thank you again!

Comment: @RodrigoLessa.. Glad to have helped :)